# Математика с большими числами и Biginteger врет

Tags: c#, biginteger, длинная-арифметика

Нужно производить простые арифметические действия над большими числами на C#. Использовал библиотеку System.Numerics. Но он не верно считает. Например

```
BigInteger first = BigInteger.Parse("1459141956031776814097256491377265401586541003894843279763498785157880955654141795");
BigInteger second = BigInteger.Parse("22248470822666314938692568397119675677137950638191323448941735236079264477232");
BigInteger result = first / second;
```

Получаю результат = 65583. Теперь если число из переменной first разделить на 65583 должно получиться число second, но это не так, получается совершенно другое число. Как реализовать, чтобы правильно посчитать?

Comment: Что значит "получается совершенно другое число", приведите конкретное число. Похоже, что у вас просто округлился ответ из-за целых чисел.

Comment: *Теперь если число из переменной first разделить на 65583 должно получиться число second* Бред. Вот если second умножить на результат, и то, что получится, отнять от first, то результат должен быть меньше second - это и есть критерий корректности результата для целочисленных вычислений.

Comment: BigInteger — ключевое слово здесь *Integer*

Comment: @Олег, когда делите целое большое на целое большое, и кладете в переменную с типом "целое большое", то результат, естественно, будет целочисленным. Следовательно, вам нужен какой-то другой тип.

Comment: Судя по последней цифре чисел: 5 % 2 = 1. Уже целого числа не получается при делении.

Answer (score 2):

Сделаем небольшое исследование, попробуем просчитать хотя бы приблизительный результат деления.
У каждого числа отбрасываем последние 72 знака.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тогда у нас остается:
`1459141956 / 22248` с такими числами можно оперировать в калькуляторе, что примерно равно: `65585`.
По-этому, мне кажется, что считает вполне правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнено:**
Если Вас смущает отсутствие дробной части числа, но необходимо ознакомится с 
[правилами деления чисел в C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/division-operator) , особенно этой частью:

```
When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. 
For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. 
This is not to be confused with floored division, 
as the / operator rounds towards zero: -7 / 3 is -2.
To obtain a quotient as a rational number, use the float, double, or decimal types
```

То есть, Вам нужно вместо `BigInteger` для `second` и `result` использовать тип с плавающей точкой: `float`, `double` или же его аналог в библиотеке больших чисел.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно посчитать точно, без округлений и укорачиваний. Нужно чтобы на выходе получилось символ в символ.

Comment: @Олег, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1.** Приведение к типу `double`.

```
BigInteger first = BigInteger.Parse("1459141956031776814097256491377265401586541003894843279763498785157880955654141795");
BigInteger second = BigInteger.Parse("22248470822666314938692568397119675677137950638191323448941735236079264477232");

Console.WriteLine($"Result: {(double)first / (double)second}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Да, точность уменьшается, но всё равно остаётся достаточно большой; Вы же не ракету в космос запускаете?..

---

**Вариант 2.** Использование `BigInteger.DivRem()`.

Метод [`DivRem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает остаток от деленя двух `BigInteger`, но остаток - это не дробная часть.

```
BigInteger first = BigInteger.Parse("1459141956031776814097256491377265401586541003894843279763498785157880955654141795");
BigInteger second = BigInteger.Parse("22248470822666314938692568397119675677137950638191323448941735236079264477232");

BigInteger quotient = BigInteger.DivRem(first, second, out BigInteger remainder);

Console.WriteLine($"Result: {quotient}\nRemainder: {remainder}");    
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

**Вариант 3.** Использование библиотеки `BigRational`.

```
Numerics.BigRational result = new Numerics.BigRational(first, second);
```

---

Я считаю, что первый вариант - наилучшее решение.

*Сам с `Ruby` не работал, но видел как знакомый на курсах показывал калькулятор с нереально большими числами. Может можно написать .dll на похожем языке и подключить в ваше приложение, но это так, мысли в слух.*

Comment: Напишите, какой результат в первом варианте получился? Я пробовал на python, и при делении исходных чисел, и приведенных к double получается результат `65583.92114505376`. https://ideone.com/GU3Yjr

Comment: На питоне точнее, я тоже пробовал на нем.. На c# получилось 65583.9211450538.

Comment: Вообще суть.. Нужно зная первое число как-то получить второе в точности. Вот я и предположил, что разделив первое на воторое получу некое значение и в дальнейшем при делении первого числа на это значение смогу получать второе число

Comment: @Олег, из-за того, что в машинном виде числа с плавающей точкой в принципе хранятся с ограниченной точностью, вы никогда не получите исходное число с точностью до последней цифры. Вот если использовать рациональный тип, то исходное число (делимое) получите, а если с плавающей точкой (double) - то нет.

Comment: @Олег _Нужно зная первое число как-то получить второе в точности._ Зачем изобретать велосипед? Используйте шифрование, у вас будет зашифрованное значение (первое число), ключ (результат деления) и оригинальное значение (второе число).

Comment: @Олег, я тут немного поэкспериментировал с типом `Decimal` в Python, оказалось, что чтобы получить `second` из `first` и `result`, нужна точность в 77 десятичных знаков как минимум. При 76 знаках уже дает разницу с "эталонным" `second` на 2. https://ideone.com/W94k0x Если числа будут разные, то и точность нужна будет разная. Я думаю, оптимальнее тут использовать рациональный тип, а не тип с плавающей или фиксированной точкой.